# Escada JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
"use strict"
let array = []
function exibeNumero(entrada) {
    for (let i = 0; i < entrada; i++) {
        array.push("#".repeat(i))
    }
    for (const entrada of array) {
        console.log(entrada)
    }
}
exibeNumero(10)
```

Estou tentando mudar o lado da escada.
Esse é o resultado que estou tendo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero inverter o lado dela, ficando assim 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Também consegue resolver utilizando apenas o [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) que já tem no seu código. A ideia é primeiro escrever uma determinada quantidade de espaços e de seguida junta com uma quantidade de `#` que faça sentido para a linha em que vai.

Num cenário em que o tamanho final é de 5 carateres, cada linha teria os seguintes carateres:

- 4 espaços, 1 #
- 3 espaços, 2 #
- 2 espaços, 3 #
- 1 espaço, 4 #
- 0 espaços, 5 #

Implementação:

```js
let array = []
function exibeNumero(entrada) {
    for (let i = 0; i < entrada; i++) {
        array.push(" ".repeat(entrada - i - 1) + "#".repeat(i + 1))
        //          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^
    }
    for (const entrada of array) {
        console.log(entrada)
    }
}
exibeNumero(5)
```

A unica instrução alterada foi a que coloca o elemento no array. Repare que foi necessário trocar o próprio repeat do `#` para que da primeira vez já escrevesse um caratere em vez de zero.

Answer (score 3):

Tente usar esse loop:

```
for (const linha of array) {
    console.log(linha.padStart(entrada-1, ' '))
}
```

O método [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) adiciona o caractere passado como segundo parâmetro no início da string, até que ela atinja o tamanho passado no primeiro parâmetro.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução:

```
function escada (n){   

    var array = [];
    var cont = 1;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        array[i] = '#'.repeat(cont).padStart(n);
        cont++;
    }
    return array;
}
```